# DB2 - Return the smallest datetime within the Select

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following SQL statement in BD2 that returns the table below

```
SELECT
c.CREATEDATE AS "Data e Hora do Alerta"
,c.SENDFROM  AS "Enviado Por"   
,c.SENDTO AS "Para"
,c.SUBJECT AS "Assunto"
FROM  M.LOG c
WHERE c.SENDFROM  = 'alerta@vomcoo.com' 
AND c.SUBJECT  = 'ALERTA - SLA estourado'
AND c.ID  = '4355070'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yofc.png)

However, I only need the smallest date and time found, highlighted in yellow in the printout

I filtered out the c.ID = '4355070' for testing only.

I have several IDs that have N lines, the idea would be to bring the smallest date/time value of each ID

I've already tried using GROUP BY , but the "To" column has different values

I need to get the first date/time of the first alert issued and "To" who it was sent to

Thanks

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returns only one (arbitrary) row for the same (ID, CREATEDATE).

```
SELECT
  c.CREATEDATE AS "Data e Hora do Alerta"
, c.SENDFROM  AS "Enviado Por"   
, c.SENDTO AS "Para"
, c.SUBJECT AS "Assunto"
FROM
(
  -- Your original SELECT statement emulation
  SELECT 
    *
  , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CREATEDATE) AS RN_
  FROM 
  (
    VALUES
      (10, CURRENT TIMESTAMP    , 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '11', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')
    , (10, CURRENT TIMESTAMP    , 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '12', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')
    , (10, CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 1, 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '13', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')

    , (20, CURRENT TIMESTAMP    , 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '21', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')
    , (20, CURRENT TIMESTAMP    , 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '22', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')
    , (20, CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 1, 'alerta@vomcoo.com', '23', 'ALERTA - SLA estourado')
  ) c (ID, CREATEDATE, SENDFROM, SENDTO, SUBJECT)
  WHERE c.SENDFROM  = 'alerta@vomcoo.com' 
  AND c.SUBJECT  = 'ALERTA - SLA estourado'
) c
WHERE RN_ = 1
```

| Data e Hora do Alerta | Enviado Por | Para | Assunto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-25-10.51.23.804000 | alerta@vomcoo.com | 11 | ALERTA - SLA estourado |
| 2023-09-25-10.51.23.804000 | alerta@vomcoo.com | 21 | ALERTA - SLA estourado |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, but multiple entries per ID could be returned if they all have the same minimum date:

```
SELECT c.CREATEDATE AS "Data e Hora do Alerta",
c.SENDFROM AS "Enviado Por",
c.SENDTO AS "Para",
c.SUBJECT AS "Assunto" 
FROM M.LOG c
WHERE c.CREATEDATE = 
   (SELECT MIN(c2.CREATEDATE) FROM M.LOG c2 WHERE c2.ID = c.ID);
```

Group by is still your friend. You may need to change which columns in the SELECT have aggregate functions on them, e.g. MAX(), MIN(), COUNT().

```
SELECT MIN(c.CREATEDATE) AS "Data e Hora do Alerta",
c.SENDFROM AS "Enviado Por",
c.SENDTO AS "Para",
c.SUBJECT AS "Assunto" 
FROM M.LOG c
GROUP BY c.ID
ORDER BY MIN(c.CREATEDATE);
```

You may need to slowly add columns and troubleshoot.

```
SELECT c.ID, MIN(c.CREATEDATE)
FROM M.LOG c
GROUP BY c.ID
ORDER BY MIN(c.CREATEDATE) DESC;
```